# How to create an array with help of a loop

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, loops, instance-variables

I have a model Image:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :description, :name, :quality, :size
end
```

I now have an instance variable with a bunch of images:

```
@images = Image.where("id<30")
```

I want to create a `@keywords` variable with all the names of the images. In the Rails console I can do:

```
for i in 0...@image.count
  puts @image[i].name
end
```

and I get a list of all the name of the images.

How can I define the `@keywords` variable in my `images_controller` in order to store this list in an array?

```
@keywords = ...?
```

The output should be a list, preferrably comma seperated, with the image names:

```
"Blue ocean, Green leafs, Sunset in New York"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@keywords = @images.collect{|i| i.name}.join(",")
```

This will get an array of all the names and join them into a comma-separated string.

Comment: shorter: `@images.map(&:name).join(',')` :-)

Comment: shorter: `@images.map(&:name) * ','` if we're playing that game.

Comment: Is this just "nice" to change it to the short version or is this also a performance issue, means the query will take less time?

Comment: This is mostly syntactic sugar - according to the docs, #map is an alias of collect and #* with a string is the same as join.  Whether or not the &:name syntax is any faster than the block I provided, I'm not sure.